# Passing JSON files through an API - node async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am writing a small program which reads some JSON files, passes the content to an API, then saves the response in some more JSON files. A pretty simple task, and the code works fine, but I have been away from node for a few years and wanted to make sure I'm using all this new async stuff right! Any comments welcome.

Node version 10.16.3

```js
'use strict'

require('dotenv').config()
const fs = require("fs")
const util = require("util")
const request = require("request-promise-native")
const pLimit = require("p-limit")

const inputPath = "./input-files/"
const outputPath = "./output-files/"
const limit = pLimit(2) // api limits to 2 concurrent requests on free account

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)


async function readInputFile(filePath) {
  return JSON.parse(await readFile(filePath))
}

async function callApi(content) {
  const options = {
    uri: "https://api.example.com",
    headers: {
      "key": process.env.API_KEY,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    form: {
      "field": content
    }
  }

  return await request(options)
}

async function processFile(fileName) {
  return readInputFile(inputPath + fileName)
    .then(data => callApi(data))
    .then(response => writeFile(outputPath + fileName, response))
}


const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(inputPath, {
  withFileTypes: true
}).map(item => item.name)

const promises = fileNames.map(fileName => {
  return limit(() => {
    return processFile(fileName)
  })
})

(async() => {
  const result = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log(`${result.length} files transferred`)
})()
```